# Is there a reason why I am getting "white spaces" when reading a socket from C client to Java server?

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp, bufferedreader

I am trying to implement TCP protocol using a Java Server and a C Client. When reading the first input from the client, the code works perfectly normal. However, upon the second input from the client, the server reads " hi" or " command1" even after I have tried to remove white spaces using line = line.replaceAll("\s",""). Are these not white spaces? Is there garbage being read from C to Java? Right now, the program is being blocked after I send the second command as the server can't recognize the command with these spaces and doesn't send anything back to the client. Help or advice would be much appreciated, thank you for your time.

Here is my Java Server code below:

```
// A Java program for a Server 
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class HXServerJava 
{ 
    //initialize socket and input stream 
    private Socket          socket   = null; 
    private ServerSocket    server   = null; 
    private DataInputStream in       =  null; 

    // constructor with port 
    public HXServerJava(int port) 
    { 
        // starts server and waits for a connection 
        try
        { 
            server = new ServerSocket(port); 
            System.out.println("Server started"); 

            System.out.println("Waiting for a client ..."); 

            socket = server.accept(); 
            System.out.println("Client accepted"); 

            // takes input from the client socket 
            BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            String line = ""; 

            // reads message from client until "over" is sent 
            while (!line.equals("over")) 
            { 
                try
                { 
                    line = in.readLine(); 
                    System.out.println("line before is: " + line);
                    line = line.replaceAll("\\s",""); //trying to get rid of whitespace
                    System.out.println("line after is: " + line);
                    if ((line != null && line.equals("hi")==true)) {
                        out.print("Welcome by server\n");
                        out.flush();
                        //out.close();
                    }
                    if ((line != null && line.equals("command1")==true)) {
                        out.print("first command executed\n");
                        out.flush();
                        //out.close();
                    }

                } 
                catch(IOException i) 
                { 
                    System.out.println(i); 
                } 
            } 
            System.out.println("Closing connection"); 
            out.print("exit\n");
            out.flush();
            // close connection 
            socket.close(); 
            in.close(); 
            out.close();
        } 
        catch(IOException i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        HXServerJava server = new HXServerJava(5000); 
    } 
}
```

Here is my C Client code below:

```
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 5000 
#define SA struct sockaddr 
void func(int sockfd) 
{ 
    char buff[MAX]; 
    int n,m; 
    char *str;
    int exitFlag = 0;
    str = malloc(sizeof (char) * MAX);
    while (exitFlag != 1){
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        printf("Enter the string : "); 
        n = 0; 
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n') 
            ; 
        //strcpy (str, buff);
        //strcat(str, "\n");
        printf("String is: %s\n",buff);
        m = write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        if (m < 0){
            perror ("ERROR writing to socket\n");
        }
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        m = read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        if (n < 0) {
            perror("ERROR reading from socket\n");
        }
        printf("From Server : %s\n", buff); 
        if ((strncmp(buff, "exit", 4)) == 0) { 
            exitFlag = 1;
            printf("Client Exit...\n"); 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int sockfd, connfd; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 

    // socket create and varification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
        printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // connect the client socket to server socket 
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) { 
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n"); 

    // function for chat 
    func(sockfd); 

    // close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
}
```

Comment: I don't know C, but seems like this is always sending `sizeof(buff)` bytes which probably is more than actual read (`n`) - also not sure if C is using same charset as java (default system one)

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was something small I was missing. This was it! Sending just n bytes instead of sizeof(buff) fixed my issue. Thank you! Also, I cant seem to mark it as solved for your comment, but thank you so much!

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `printf("socket creation failed...\n");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error indication is from a C library function, should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest using `perror()`

Comment: regarding: `exit(0); `  in general, returning 0 from `main()` indicates success.  Suggest using: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Please make your comment an answer, so that the OP can mark it.